# how to add a friend system to django

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-views, django-queryset

I have been trying to add a friend system to django in which the user can add and remove friends, in the process I found a Friend matching query does not exist error and shows that this part of the code is bad:

```
    friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
```

now here I will leave the complete code.

views.py

```
    def profile(request, username=None):
        friend = Friend.objects.get(current_user=request.user)
        friends = friend.users.all()
        if username:
          post_owner = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
          user_posts=Post.objects.filter(user_id=post_owner) 
        else:
          post_owner = request.user
          user_posts=Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        args1 = {
          'post_owner': post_owner,
          'user_posts': user_posts,
          'friends': friends,
        }
        return render(request, 'profile.html', args1)

    def change_friends(request, operation, pk):
        friend = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        if operation == 'add':
          Friend.make_friends(request.user, friend)
        elif operation == 'remove':
          Friend.lose_friends(request.user, friend)
        return redirect('profile')
```

models.py

```
    class Friend(models.Model):
        users = models.ManyToManyField(User, default='users', blank=True, related_name='users')
        current_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

        @classmethod
        def make_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
            friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
                current_user=current_user
            )
            friend.users.add(new_friend)

        @classmethod
        def lose_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
            friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
                current_user=current_user
            )
            friend.users.remove(new_friend)
```

if the profile.html is neede please let me know:)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a friend system on django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61831356/add-a-friend-system-on-django)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request.user has no Friend record as the error indicates. You can simple change the get operation to `filter`&`first` operations. `Friend.objects.filter(current_user=request.user).first()` then do not forget to check friend instance exists. So your view should be something like:

```
def profile(request, username=None):
    friend = Friend.objects.filter(current_user=request.user).first()
    friends = []
    if friend:   
        friends = friend.users.all()
    if username:
        post_owner = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user_id=post_owner) 
    else:
        post_owner = request.user
        user_posts = Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    args1 = {
        'post_owner': post_owner,
        'user_posts': user_posts,
        'friends': friends,
    }
    return render(request, 'profile.html', args1)
```

Comment: Wow, your code just saved my life!! can I ask what does "friends = [ ]" mean?

Comment: It is something just to prevent NoneTypeError when passing friends as context. We need to define all variables sending through args1 dictionary.