# Add a friend system on django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-views

I have been trying to add friend system in which the user can add and remove friends (other users), after finishing with the code, I found an error that when the logedin user tries to add a friend from other user's profile, the add friend button redirects to the logedin user profile making it imposible to add a new friend, it can just add himself as a friend. I personally think the error is on the views.py profile view.

views.py (profile shows user's profile and change_friend is the one that adds and removes frinds)

```
    def profile(request, username=None):
        friend = Friend.objects.filter(current_user=request.user).first()
        friends = []
        if friend:   
          friends = friend.users.all()
        if username:
          post_owner = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
          user_posts=Post.objects.filter(user_id=post_owner)
        else:
          post_owner = request.user
          user_posts=Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
        args1 = {
            'post_owner': post_owner,
            'user_posts': user_posts,
            'friends': friends,
        }
        return render(request, 'profile.html', args1)

    def change_friends(request, operation, pk):
        friend = User.objects.get(pk=pk)
        if operation == 'add':
          Friend.make_friend(request.user, friend)
        elif operation == 'remove':
          Friend.lose_friend(request.user, friend)
        return redirect('profile')
```

models.py

```
    class Friend(models.Model):
        users = models.ManyToManyField(User, default='users', blank=True, related_name='users')
        current_user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='owner', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

        @classmethod
        def make_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
            friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
                current_user=current_user
            )
            friend.users.add(new_friend)

        @classmethod
        def lose_friend(cls, current_user, new_friend):
            friend, created = cls.objects.get_or_create(
                current_user=current_user
            )
            friend.users.remove(new_friend)
```

profile.html

```
    <div class="media">
      <div class="media-body">
        <h2 class="account-heading">{{ post_owner.username }}</h2>
        <p class="text-secondary">{{ post_owner.email }}</p>
        {% if not user in friends %}
          <a href="{% url 'change_friends' operation='add' pk=user.pk %}">
            <button type="button">add Friend</button>
          </a>
        {% endif %}
      </div>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h2>Friends</h2>
      {% for friend in friends %}
        <p>{{ friend.username }}</p>
        <a href="{% url 'change_friends' operation='remove' pk=friend.pk %}">
          <button type="button">Remove Friend</button>
        </a>
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
        path('profile/<str:username>/', views.profile, name='profile_pk'),
        url(r'^connect/(?P<operation>.+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.change_friends, name='change_friends'),
    ]
```

Comment: I am a little confused about the html part. Do you want to achieve "post_owner (is technically same with request.user) wants to add other users as friend" this problem? If so, you need to provide "other users" in template to loop over and generate "add Friend" button each of them.

Comment: @DenizKaplan How can I provide "other users" in template to loop and generate "add Friend"?

Comment: If there is no limitation, just pass friends_to_add to your template which is result of `User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)`. If you want to remove friends of user also from queryset, just chain with `.exclude(id__in=friend.users.values_list("id"))` If this is complicated. I can explain in an answer with detailed view and html code. I have character limit in comments.

Comment: @DenizKaplan yes this looks kind of complicated to me, can you please add a answer so that I can understand better please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing the `request.user` object to the `change_friends` view, through the `user` object. By default `user == request.user` when used in a template.

Just change that line that you have in profile.html with:

```
<a href="{% url 'change_friends' operation='add' pk=post_owner.pk %}">
    <button type="button">add Friend</button>
</a>
```

Now, I note that you're redirecting the user to the `profile` view once they add a new friend, and that's not what you want. That's happening because when you're calling the `redirect()` function in your `change_friends` view, you are not passing any parameter to the `profile` view. You defined the username should be `None` by default and then you're saying that `if not username` then `post_owner` should be `request.user`

How to change this? Well, just pass the desired `username` when calling `redirect` as a keyword argument. Something as follows:

```
return redirect('profile', username=friend.username)
```

Comment: Hey! Your code make it work  but when the user is adds a friend it redirects it to the logedin user profile, what can I to just add a friend and keep it on the users profile page without redirecting it to the logedin users profile?

Comment: I'm glad it worked, my friend. If you want that operation to be performed but without changing the current page, then you should consider do an AJAX call. On the other hand, if you din't mind to reload the current page, then you should pass the `user` object as a parameter to the `redirect()` function. Let me update my answer and show you how.

Comment: username=friend.username is returning a no reverse match error, I also tried user=friend.user and returned the same error

Comment: I also noticed that when  any user adds a friend, it adds a friend to all the users, same happens when you remove a friend, sorry this is my 4th month coding

Comment: As regards to the NoReverseMatch, most likely you have not set correctly the `path()` function for the `profile` view in you urls.py. Remember to prepare the URL to receive the parameter. You should have something like: `path('profile/<username>', view.profile, name='profile')`

Comment: Yes, that is the exactly what I have, well that url is for other users profile, the url that shows the loged in user profile is `path('myprofile', views.profile, name='profile'),`

Comment: Exactly, and that's the problem. You're trying to access that view (when calling `redirect('profile', username=friend.username)`, but that view is not prepared to receive parameters (in this case, `friend.username`) in the URL. I suggest you to put it as I told you above. BTW, you should not have two different views to show the logged in user profile and the other people's. Actually the `profile` view is already prepared to show the content accordingly.

Comment: I just did as suggested and it is returning no reverse match error again, I will add the urls.py to my code (question) so that you can see it. it is basicaly the profile path and this one `url(r'^connect/(?P<operation>.+)/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.change_friends, name='change_friends'),
    ` Now that I think about it is there anything wrong with having a url and a path together?

Comment: Yes, definitely you should be consistent when coding, so if you are using `path()` there's no need to mix it up with `url()`. If you already changed the path for `profile` then now the problem must be in the template. Why? Because most likely you still have references to the old `path()` when it wasn't expecting any parameter. Make sure you update every <a> tag in your HTML pointing to `profile` view, with the desired username parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214015/discussion-between-revliscano-and-juan-martin-zabala).

Comment: hey! Revliscano can you help me with something please?

Answer (score 0):

In your view, friends address to already added friends, you want to get the users are eligible to add as friend to request.user object. To achieve this,

In your profile view:

```
def profile(request, username=None):
    friend = Friend.objects.filter(current_user=request.user).first()
    friends = []
    # In case of friend is None, I send all users except request user, to be able to add on html template.
    friends_to_add = User.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id)
    if friend:   
        friends = friend.users.all()
        # here we have a valid friend (who is the user request has)
        # so I don't want to send users to template who are already friend of request user.
        friends_to_add = friends_to_add.exclude(id__in=friend.users.values_list("id"))
    if username:
        post_owner = get_object_or_404(User, username=username)
        user_posts=Post.objects.filter(user_id=post_owner)
    else:
        post_owner = request.user
        user_posts=Post.objects.filter(user=request.user)
    args1 = {
        'post_owner': post_owner,
        'user_posts': user_posts,
        'friends': friends,
        'friends_to_add': friends_to_add,
    }
    return render(request, 'profile.html', args1)
```

In your template file, you can use them as:

```
<div class="media">
     <div class="media-body">
        <h2 class="account-heading">{{ post_owner.username }}</h2>
        <p class="text-secondary">{{ post_owner.email }}</p>
        {% for user in friends_to_add %}
            <a href="{% url 'change_friends' operation='add' pk=user.pk %}">
                <button type="button">add Friend</button>
            </a>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will make sense to you. You can ask me anything you cannot understand above from comments if you need.

Comment: This makes sense but I think I wasn't clear from what I want, the problem is that the code is showing the loged in user's friends in every user's profile page, the goal is to show the friends from the selected user in their profile page just like in facebook.

Comment: My mistake, I got it now. You can pass `user.pk` or `post_owner.pk` in the url tag.

Comment: you mean that I can use `{% url 'change_friends' operation='add' pk=user.pk %}` and `{% url 'change_friends' operation='add' pk=post_owner.pk %}`?

Comment: Yes, you can choose one of them. If you get another error on adding_friend, please provide the logs that I can help better.